# Find upper and lower bound given limit for submultiplicative sequence

Tags: limits, inequality

I am working on an exercise and I am confused on the boundary situation.

Suppose $q_t,t\geq0$ satisfy $0 \leq q_{t} \leq 1$ and submultiplicative property, i.e.

$$q_{t+s}\leq q_s q_t$$
and we have ($\lambda$ is a constant, $\lambda \in (0, \infty)$)
$$\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log (q_{t}e^{\lambda t})}{t}=0$$
then it is said that: there exists $0<c_{1}<c_{2}<\infty$ such that for all $t$,
$$
c_{1}  \leq q_{t}e^{\lambda t} \leq c_{2} 
$$
I try to find $c_1,c_2$ but I fails, notice that $log(q_t)/t$ is decreasing as t increase. The situation as $t \rightarrow 0$ is unknown. And also if $\log (q_{t}e^{\lambda t})=\small o(t)$, then limit goes to zero. How can we know that $q_{t}e^{\lambda t} \leq c_{2} $ ?

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I can Prove one side of inequality:

From Wikipedia:

**Theorem**:  For every measurable subadditive function $f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ the limit $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}$ exists and is equal to $\inf _{t>0} \frac{f(t)}{t} .$

Hence

$$\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log \left(q_{t} \right)}{t}=\inf _{t>0} \frac{\log (q_t)}{t}=-\lambda$$
So for any $t>0$,$\frac{\log (q_t)}{t}\geq-\lambda\Longrightarrow 1 \leq q_{t} e^{\lambda t}$. This prove the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas (too long for a comment):

The existence of $c_2$ can be argued: Let $f(t) = q_{t}e^{\lambda t} $. The submultiplicative property gives
$$
\frac{f(s+t)}{f(t) f(s)} = \frac{q_{s+t}}{q_t q_s} \leq 1
$$
Now fix $s=1$, then $f(t+1) < f(t)f(1)$ and iterating this, $f(t) < f(t_0)f(1)^t$ with $0< t_0 <1$. So $f(t)$ grows at most exponentially with $t$, hence $\lambda =  \log(f(1))$. Likewise, fixing $s=1/2$, we get  $f(t) < f(t_0)f(1/2)^{2t}$, hence $\lambda =  2 \log(f(1/2))$, etc.

For establishing the existence of an upper bound, we could use this, provided we can show $f(1) \le  1$ or $f(1/2) \le  1$ etc.. How do we do this?

I wonder for the lower bound to be $c_1 >0$ (and not $c_1 \ge 0$). From $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log (q_{t}e^{\lambda t})}{t}=  0$ we know only that $f(t)$ must behave sub-exponentially: it doesn't even say if $f(t)$ should be rising or falling.   Suppose $f(t) \propto 1/t$, then the limit is satisfied but $c_1 =  0$. How do we rule this out?